# Processing odd and even values

Tags: go

I'm learning about channels and concurrency in GO and I'm stuck on a task.
I want to function that passes a slice, filters the numbers and then prints the channel values. The issue is that when I use the channel it deadlocks the program. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func processOdd(inputs []int) chan int {
    oddValues := make(chan int)
    for _, numbers := range inputs {
        go func(num int) {
            if num%2 != 0 {
                oddValues <- num
            }
        }(numbers)
    }
    return oddValues
}

func processEven(inputs []int) chan int {
    evenValues := make(chan int)
    for _, numbers := range inputs {
        go func(num int) {
            if num%2 == 0 {
                evenValues <- num
            }
        }(numbers)
    }
    return evenValues
}

func main() {
    inputs := []int{1, 17, 34, 56, 2, 8}
    evenCH := processEven(inputs)
    for range inputs {
        fmt.Print(<-evenCH)
    }
}
```

Comment: The for-loop is stuck waiting for new values from the channel, hence the deadlock. You can close the channel after all goroutines terminate to fix. Or, count the values received and break out of the loop once all numbers are received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the channel when done sending values:

```
func processEven(inputs []int) chan int {
    evenValues := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, num := range inputs {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(num int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            if num%2 == 0 {
                evenValues <- num
            }
        }(num)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(evenValues)
    }()

    return evenValues
}
```

The code uses a [WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to wait for the senders to complete.

Loop receiving values until the channel is closed:

```
func main() {
    inputs := []int{1, 17, 34, 56, 2, 8}
    evenCh := processEven(inputs)
    for num := range evenCh {
        fmt.Println(num)
    }
}
```

Range on a channel loops until the channel is closed.